# how to transfer data from one child activity to another using startChildActivity?

Tags: android, childactivity

this is my class name

```
public class Register extends TabGroupActivity
```

I am calling 2nd activity through

```
startChildActivity("Register", new Intent(Register.this,RegisterForm.class));
```

can any one help me how to transfer some data through this method

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Register.this,RegisterForm.class);
i.putExtra("name", yourdata);//i assume you are adding some string data
startChildActivity("Register", i);

//in RegisterForm.class

Intent i = RegisterForm.this.getIntent();
i.getStringExtra("name", "default Value you want");
```

Comment: thank you so much wuold you do me one more favour. may you tell how to recive data in other activity(RegisterForm.class).

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an interface called `Parecelable` and write your object inside a `Parcel` so that you can transport it through the `Intent`

This tutorial will teach you how to do that

http://www.codexperience.co.za/post/passing-an-object-between-activities-using-an-intent